# Trying to work with bootstrap pagination with PHP mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello i am trying to make a pagination using bootstrap im trying to display all results for mySQL data and limit the data to 10 every page, can anyone help me with this, thank you in advance this is my code

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM backend_account WHERE archives = '0' ORDER BY account_id DESC LIMIT 10 ");

Answer (score 0):

you need php code?

```
<?php
$pre = '0';
$next = '10';
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM backend_account WHERE archives = '0' ORDER BY account_id DESC LIMIT ".$pre." , ".$next.")";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LIMIT` and OFFSET to accomplish this.

Given you are grabbing 10 records at a time you would supply your OFFSET,LIMIT like this:

**First page of results**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM backend_account WHERE archives = '0' ORDER BY account_id DESC LIMIT 0,10 ");
```

Offset is zero based so this will start from the first record and grab 10 records.

**Second Page of results**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM backend_account WHERE archives = '0' ORDER BY account_id DESC LIMIT 10,10 ");
```

Offset is 10 this time (11th record) and grab 10 records

**Third Page of results**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM backend_account WHERE archives = '0' ORDER BY account_id DESC LIMIT 20,10 ");
```

Offset is 20 this time (21st) record and  grab 10 records.

So you need to pass your offset to the same page. When you are building your pagination, you can set up your links like this:

```
<?php
// If page is supplied set offset or default to zero for first page
$page = ($_GET['page']) ? ($_GET['page'] * 10) - 10 : 0;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM backend_account WHERE archives = '0' ORDER BY account_id DESC LIMIT $page,10 ");

<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?page=1 ?>">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?page=2 ?>">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?page=3 ?>">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?page=4 ?>">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?page=5 ?>">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is an **extremely** trivial example to demonstrate how this could work. In production I would recommend generating the pagination using PHP and providing additional logic to add `active` class to the `li` by using a map method or foreach loop to create your list items.